# Comic where someone's shadow is cut away

Tags: story-identification, comics, the-sandman, 2000ad

[This](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/260247/short-story-or-stories-where-shadows-can-be-cut-away-from-a-person) recent question stirred a vague memory.

I'm sure it is a different work to the one in the linked thread.  It was a comic, not prose.

Basically, I have an image of someone cutting away someone's shadow with a big pair of scissors, then rolling up the shadow and putting it in his pocket.

I think it must have been somewhere between 1990-2000 that I read it.

I'm pretty sure it was a short story. Single issue, or just a few pages. Or a minor subplot if it was in a longer story.

It *may* have been in *2000AD*, or Neil Gaiman's *Sandman*. But I can't swear to it.

Comment: This stirred a memory in me as well. I didn't read Sandman during that time, but I was an avid 2000AD reader (as well as JDM) during the 90s, so it may have been in there.

Comment: This sounds familiar to me too.  I think the one doing the cutting was a Joker/Jester type figure

Comment: In Sandman: Brief Lives, a character known as the Alder Man cuts off his shadow and has it pretend to be him (while he hides as a bear)

Comment: That's a pretty common trope. If you want it narrow like that, than what Valorum said.

Comment: The Alder Man _chews_ his shadow off, and the shadow then walks off on its own. Your description, on the other hand, reminds of a scene from _Vampire Hunter D: Bloodlust_, though it's a feature-length animation. But maybe the same scene was present in a manga of whatnot

Comment: If so, it's not one I've read, or even heard of.

Answer (score 4):

The Sandman, Brief Lives, chapter 3 (issue 44) has something similar. In it, the alder man (a sort of laponic shaman) realizes that he is about to die if he remains human. So he transforms into a bear then claws and eats part of his own shadow, to sever it from himself.

[image: Alder man picture one]

Then his shadow walk in his shape, in an attempt to fool death.

[image: Alder man 2]

In one of the later issues, Fates use scissors to cut a thread of life.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think that's what I remember. But thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

This was an element in a storyline in Grant Morrison's Doom Patrol.

Comment: Can you pinpoint any specific issues?  This would be a much better answer with more details, or best of all, some actual frames from the comic.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I've never read Doom Patrol, so I don't think that's it.